# Local-Notification plugin with PhoneGap Build not working

Tags: cordova, notifications, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm using PhoneGap Build to make apps for iOS and Android. Trying to add Local Notification functionality but I can't figure out what is wrong.

The app builds, installs, and can run other plugins like vibration. But following the steps on the plugin page (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) don't seem to be working.

I added the following line to the config.xml file to load the plugin.

```
<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" />
```

Then in my index.html file I put the following code in the script tags. Both taken directly from the sample code page (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/11.-Samples).

The first bit of code is this which makes the object available.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
// window.plugin.notification.local is now available
}, false);
```

and this line is supposed to create a local notification immediately.

```
window.plugin.notification.local.add({ message: 'Great app!' });
```

I made a skeleton app which doesn't do anything else but show a notification. The app builds fine and installs but I do not get a notification of any sort.

Am I missing something about how the plugin is supposed to be implemented? Or is there a way to at least test that the plugin is being installed? I am testing on Android.

Answer (score 1):

@WD-40, I'm using: `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />`. This is NOT push notification, but the "alert()" box variant.

If this works for you, my working source code for PGB (3.2) is available here:
http://codesnippets.altervista.org/examples/phonegap/demos/PUBLIC.Apps.html

You can clone from github.

Comment: I'm looking for local notification which is kinda between push notification and app alerts. They are set by the app but don't require the app to be running. Thanks for the link to your suite of test apps. Those look handy.

Comment: You really need a service. Most of them have the kinks worked out. I think UrbanAirship http://urbanairship.com/ is the most popular. -Jesse

Comment: The reason I'm looking to use local notifications is to sidestep having to use a service. Since local notifications come from the app, you don't need a service. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html

Comment: Okay. My confusion. There is a large amount of noise surrounding both "remote" and "local" notifications. At the present, they are getting confused on the forums. Some people think Local mean Remote, and so forth. Sorry this is off my path. The advice I can offer is  I think you'll need something that can run in the background. ---- Sorry for the distraction. Sorry I could not help. Thanks very much for the clarification. --- Don't forget to try the Google Group. It seems much better than this SOvrflw stuff.

Comment: The plugin takes care of everything so no app service needs to be coded or run. I assume it just rides off of built in mobile OS stuff similar to how an alarm would work. All of the work has been done and figured out functionality wise, My only issue is just turning the thing on to tap into it.